# Crob Job Warning: proc_open(): fork failed

Tags: cron, magento2.2

i running this cron job

```
php bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule"
```

but getting this message, how can i do? thank you

```
Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 993#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', '/home/XXX/...', 993, Array)
#1 /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(993): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(786): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(747): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(681): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(135): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->renderException(Object(Exception), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput))
#6 /home/XXX/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#7 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase php memory limit.
As an initial approach you could try:

```
php -d memory_limit=YOUR_LIMIT bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule"
```

Comment: my memory_limit is 1G , So i need php -d memory_limit=1G bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" ? @Bartosz Herba

Comment: Apparently process you try to run exhaust it all, that is why you can try to increase it runtime with cli command and if it will work for some value af assigned memory then you could perform refactorization steps in appropriate place. So far it is a memory limit issue.

Comment: if i run this : "php -d memory_limit=1g bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule"" ,  so need delete "php bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule""? kind regards

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: sorry my english not good,my meaning is if my memory_limit is 1G, so how can i do fix this issue?beacuse i getting this message.kind regards

Comment: i added your code,but getting new message. mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 23068672) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php on line 1299

Comment: I wanted you to run this command with custom memory limitation for php scripts to grasp what is the actual requirement for memory resource. Then you should refactor your code or permanently increase memory limit on server. Magento 2 requires up to 2G of memory (for testing) so I assume that with some custom code this requirement might be higher.